# Docker-compose - node_modules not being populated at host

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build the following service with docker-compose.yml:

```
  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
```

**Dockerfile-dev**

```
# base image
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json

RUN npm install 
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.2 -g 

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "react-html-parser":"^2.0.2",
    "spotify-web-api-js": "^0.22.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

structure:

```
services/ 
        client/
              node_modules/
              src/
                 components/
                           Seeds.jsx
```

but node_modules is not being populated when I build 'client' with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build client
```

all I get is:

*structure*

```
node_modules/  
            .cache/ 
                  balel-loader/
```

and `Seeds.jsx` is throwing errors like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/code-frame'
```

build log:

```
Building client
Step 1/7 : FROM node:11.6.0-alpine
 ---> 9036ebdbc59d
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in d14769781678
Removing intermediate container d14769781678
 ---> e66dfb9c7df4
Step 3/7 : ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 93481b2c4091
Removing intermediate container 93481b2c4091
 ---> f65f848253e2
Step 4/7 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
 ---> 84919d704058
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in ddd9633a6d77
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: Way too old
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.4: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js-pure@3.1.3 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1913 packages from 738 contributors and audited 36636 packages in 83.844s
found 68 vulnerabilities (63 low, 5 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing intermediate container ddd9633a6d77
 ---> 94121327cd15
Step 6/7 : RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.2 -g
 ---> Running in 2fb4c77cba98
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: Way too old
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.4: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
/usr/local/bin/react-scripts -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js-pure@3.1.3 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ react-scripts@2.1.2
added 1937 packages from 671 contributors in 51.761s
Removing intermediate container 2fb4c77cba98
 ---> 70985fc9b272
Step 7/7 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Running in 2ad6e5d0a606
Removing intermediate container 2ad6e5d0a606
 ---> a11dc9538db6

Successfully built a11dc9538db6
Successfully tagged dev3_client:latest
```

note:

I have tried deleting container and volumes, building with `build --no-cache`, as well as removing this line:

```
- '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
```

to no avail. what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe because volumes get mounted later in the process. Try to COPY the directory in the Dockerfile and see if it works

Comment: using which command? I mean the one liner.

Comment: this is where the code was extracted: https://testdriven.io/courses/microservices-with-docker-flask-and-react/part-two-react-and-docker/, and dockerfile here is how it ends up, without `package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volumes are mounted on run-time, and `RUN` commands are executed when building the image. Your approach is flawed, you need to re-think how it works and what the goals are.

One alternative could be to run `npm install` in the `ENTRYPOINT` with a script:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Where `entrypoint.sh` contains something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install
exec $*
```